# Trigger.IO: Missing APK file when attempting to run

Tags: android, trigger.io

I'm developing an Android app using Trigger.IO & Forge. If I package my app into an APK and manually install it with ADB, I have no issues.

However, if I call the "run" command, I get the following errors:

```
[INFO] Creating Android .apk file

[INFO] Creating APK with aapt

[INFO] Signing APK with a debug key

[INFO] Aligning apk

[INFO] Installing apk

[ERROR] Communication with adb failed: Missing APK file

[ERROR]
```

It appears that the temporary apk file that is generated gets deleted before ADB can send it to my device.

Does anyone know a solution to this issue?

Comment: try to clean and rebuild your project

Comment: Trigger.IO doesn't have clean/rebuild commands. Regardless, I deleted any build files, rebuilt and had the same issues